# RoleManager in asp.net core web app working with different tables

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have Four tables (Student, AspNetUsers, AspNetUserRoles and AspNetRoles).
I have three roles (user, Teacher, Admin).
The teacher/Admin creates a user account(fields ie Email, phone, address, role) with the user role and this is saved in the **student** table. The teacher gives an Email to the student.
The student creates an account with an Email(Created by teacher/Admin) and password and this is saved in the **AspNetUsers** table.
**My Question Is:**  How to assign a role to the student that is given by the Teacher/Admin in **AspNetUserRoles** table (UserID and UserRoleId). *UserId is in AspNetUsers table and UserRoleId is in student table*

```
    public class RolesAdminController : Controller    
     {
       private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
       public ApplicationUserManager UserManager;
       private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
       

       public RolesAdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
            ApplicationRoleManager roleManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            RoleManager = roleManager;   
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(string returnUrl = null)
        {
         returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
         if(ModelState.IsValid){
           var user = new IdentityUser{Username = Input.Name, Email = Input.Email};
           var result = await _UserManager.CreateAsync(user,Input.Password);
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
          
         }
        }
```

I have no idea.. What should I add in my code to do it? Assign a role to the student that should be done while the student Register the account.
**Need Help**

Answer (score 0):

Here is hoping that you have your startup code wired up correctly to include the AddRoleManager method like so

```
  services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Then your code is tweeked a bit since it seems as though you are tring to make the call from an api endpoint instead of an actual web page, hence issues such as redirecting to a return url will be handled by the caller when they assess whether the response from the api call they made succeeded or not. Note also that I use IdentityUser instead of ApplicationUser, but you can swap it out if you are using the later. Anyway, the code should give you a gist of how to implement it in your own project

```
 public class RolesAdminController : ControllerBase
{
    private UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public RolesAdminController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
         RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(InputDto inputDto)
    {
        inputDto ??= new InputDto(); // if input is null, create new input
        
        List<string> errors = inputDto.Errors();
        if (errors.Any())
        {
            return BadRequest(errors);
        }

        var user = new IdentityUser(){ UserName = inputDto.Name, Email = inputDto.Email };
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, inputDto.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return BadRequest(result.Errors); //You can turn that errors object into a list of string if you like
        }

        string roleName = "";
        switch (inputDto.RoleType)
        {
            case RoleType.User:
                roleName = "user";
                break;
            case RoleType.Teacher:
                roleName = "Teacher";
                break;
            case RoleType.Admin:
                roleName = "Admin";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        //Checking if role is in not system
        if(!(await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName)))
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
        }

        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);

        return Ok(); //Or you can return Created(uriToTheCreatedResource);
    }
}

public class InputDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public RoleType RoleType { get; set; }

    public List<string> Errors()
    {
        List<string> vtr = new List<string>();
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
        {
            vtr.Add("Name Cannot be null");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email))
        {
            vtr.Add("Email Cannot be null");
        }

        //Do the rest of your validation

        return vtr;
    }
}

public enum RoleType
{
    User, Teacher, Admin
}
```